Performance impact on using multiple Where function on Cosmos db query
If I have a querable from a Cosmos DB container. What's the performance impact if I write code in these two different ways?

query.Where(x=>x.a=1 && x.b=2);
query.Where(x=>x.a=1).Where(x=>x.b=2);

I tried to get the query expression with query.Expression.ToString(), but the output is still very c# code like, not sql-like. So, I don't know what kind of query it will execute on the server side.
Would the two queries generate same/similar server side query?
Is there a way to get the generated sql query like they did in this document?
Thanks

I would suggest benchmarking and evaluating the RU cost of each, along with total time of each. I really don't think there's an absolute answer, aside from benchmark. That aside: it's unclear what document you're referring to, as your link is to a fairly long article. All details should be here in your question, so it's a good idea to include a sample document here.

You could try to parse your delegate (Func<>) of IQueryable<> to string to get the desired result.
The LINQ provider for Cosmos DB will combine the conditions into a single WHERE clause on the server side, regardless of whether you used one .Where() or multiple chained calls.
Both your examples will generate the same query:
SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.a = 1 AND c.b = 2

The Cosmos DB LINQ provider is good enough in optimizing the query translation, so you can safely operate the both options.
